# LINQ Lambda - Find all ID's in one list that don't exist in another list

Tags: linq, lambda

I have two collections of objects (List list1 and List list2). There is a property on each called "ID". I know that list2 will always have more items than list1, I just need an easy way to get a collection of all the items that exist in list2 but not list1 using LINQ lambda expressions.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you only need the IDs of the items then [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835532/linq-lambda-find-all-ids-in-one-list-that-dont-exist-in-the-other-list/3835544#3835544) will do the trick nicely. If you need to return the items themselves (and they don't already have a suitable `Equals` implementation) then you could try something like this:

```
// assumes that the ID property is an int - change the generic type if it's not
var ids = new HashSet<int>(list1.Select(x => x.ID));
var results = list2.Where(x => !ids.Contains(x.ID));
```

Comment: Why put into a hashset? (Could do: var ids = list1.Select(x => x.ID); )

Comment: @David_001: You could do that, but then the `Contains` lookup would be O(n), rather than O(1), making the query as a whole O(n*m) rather than O(n+m). Admittedly, this probably wouldn't be noticeable for smaller collections, but if there were many items then performance would really suffer without the O(1) lookup provided by `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't considered performance. The HashSet will be much quicker in pretty much all situations, but especially for large sizes of list2. For that reason it's the best solution to this problem, but I think you may have overlooked the constructor cost for HashSet in your big O sums. Specifically, if list2 is going to be very small (say 10 items), the Contains is not the only bottleneck, the creation of the ids list is, and the following will be quicker (no matter the size of list1): "var ids = list1.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();"

Answer (score 23):

This will get you the IDs that are only in list2:

```
var ids = list2.Select(x => x.Id).Except(list1.Select(x => x.Id));
```

If your objects compare equal when they have the same ID then you can simplify it to:

```
var objects = list2.Except(list1);
```