# Take Action on Item in List B If That Item Does Not Exist in List A

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two lists of the same class type. The properties of the class are:

```
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string Severity { get; set; }
 public DateTime DetectedMissingUTC { get; set; }
 public DateTime DetectedMissingLocal { get; set; }
```

Consider a case where List A contains the following:

```
[0] Item.Name = "Bob"
[1] Item.Name = "Rob"
```

And List B contains:

```
[0] Item.Name = "Bob"
[1] Item.Name = "Rob"
[2] Item.Name = "Robert"
```

I would like to do something with `[2] Item.Name = "Robert"` because it's a new entry. How can I code for this? In gibberish pseudo-code terms I need:

```
foreach (var ListB.item NOT IN ListA)
{
  Do something with item
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835532/linq-lambda-find-all-ids-in-one-list-that-dont-exist-in-the-other-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
foreach (var  item in ListB.Where(x => !ListA.Any(a => a.Name == x.Name))
{
    ...
}
```

If you want to add all items to `listA` that is only exists in `ListB`, you can do:

```
ListA.AddRange(ListB.Where(x => !ListA.Any(a => a.Name == x.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do. If you don't know how to define the CustomEqualityComparer just Google `IEqualityComparer`.

```
foreach (var item in ListB.Except(ListA, new CustomEqualityComparer())
{
    item.DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var newItem = ListB.Select(c => c.Name).Except(ListA.Select(c = c.Name));
//make use of your new item.
Console.Write(newItem.Name);
```